# Python service fails with error 1053 but works with debug mode

Tags: python, py2exe, pywin32

I am trying to create Python service .exe from my code.
I've stuck on running it.

I have 2 important files: service code:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import time
from mailbox.fetcher import main_fetching
from disc.my_logger import set_up_logging

logging = set_up_logging("Fetcher")


class FetcherSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "MailMan-FetchingService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "MailMan FetchingService"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.stop_event = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        self.stop_requested = False

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.stop_event)
        logging.info('Stopping fetching ...')
        self.stop_requested = True

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        servicemanager.LogMsg(
            servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
            servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
            (self._svc_name_,'')
        )
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        logging.info(' ** Starting fetching mails service ** ')
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        while not self.stop_requested:
            main_fetching()
```

The py2exe setup code:

```
setup(console=[{"script": "fetching_service.py",
                "icon_resources": [(1, "../mailman.ico")],
                "dest_base": "fetching_service"}],
      data_files=[('', ['../cacert.pem', '../trusted-certs.crt'])],
      options={"py2exe": {
          "includes": ["win32serviceutil", "win32service", "win32event"],
          'bundle_files': 0, "optimize": 2,
          'dist_dir': 'fetcher_service'}})
```

The service installs properly:

```
$ fetcher_service/fetching_service.exe --startup=delayed install
Installing service MailMan-FetchingService
Changing service configuration
Service updated
```

But on starting:

```
$ fetcher_service/fetching_service.exe start
Starting service MailMan-FetchingService
Error starting service: Usługa nie odpowiada na sygnał uruchomienia lub sygnał sterujący w oczekiwanym czasie.
```

(Translating to english:  the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion)
I've tries setting specific user, but it did not help...
Moreover: error occures INSTANTLY after running, there is no delay

Forgot to add: service works perfectly in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must signal Windows that your service is actually running. Inside `SvcDoRun`, call

```
self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
```

and once your service is actually started (for example once you reach main, or even directly afterwards)

```
self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
```

to mark your service as *sucessfully started*.

Comment: Unfortunatelly: it didn't help... I've added your suggestions to the code above.

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be caused by a broken pywin32 install. Using Sys Internals excellent procmon I found that pythonservice.exe was failing to load pywintypes34.dll. Running c:\python34\scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py fixed the problem. NB if you've installed pywin32 as pypiwin32 because you used pip, then you've need to fix the C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pypiwin32_system32
dir to be C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32 for the script to work.

Comment: This was the right answer for me. When degu works, but start don't, this is the way to go. Should be the selected answer.

Comment: Works for me too.
If:
a) "python your_service.py debug" works, whilst 
b) "python your_service.py install" + start it as a service doesn't with error 1053,
try "python C:\Python27\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.
I've used phihag's answer and changes setup.py  myself:

```
setup(service=[{'modules':'fetching_service','cmdline_style':'pywin32','description':'your service description',
    # console=[{"script": "fetching_service.py",
                 "icon_resources": [(1, "../mailman.ico")],
                 "dest_base": "fetching_service"}],
      data_files=[('', ['../cacert.pem', '../trusted-certs.crt'])],
      options={"py2exe": {
          "includes": ["win32serviceutil", "win32service", "win32event"],
          'bundle_files': 0, "optimize": 2,
          'dist_dir': 'fetcher_service'}})
```